# Entering data to a form and returning the data without duplication

Tags: javascript, string, submit

I'm trying to create a form in JS that takes a low and high temp and creates an output that looks

like this graphic:[image]

The problem I keep running into is that when I hit submit the second time, it repeats everything twice. So if I enter is 30,40 the first time, and 60,80 the second. It would display:

30,40

30,40

60,80

The problem just gets worse as you enter more data.

```
'use strict';

// Reference to where the output goes:
var output = document.getElementById('output');

// Create a new object:
var todays_date = new Date();
var day = todays_date.getDate();
var month = todays_date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = todays_date.getFullYear();    

var temps_data_low = [];
var temps_data_high = [];
var temp_data_msg = "";

var sum_low = 0;
var sum_high = 0;

temp_data_msg += "Date" + ' ' + "Low Temperature" + ' ' + "High Temperature" + '<br>';

function call() {

    'use strict';

    var LowTemperature = parseFloat(document.getElementById('LowTemperature').value);
    var HighTemperature = parseFloat(document.getElementById('HighTemperature').value);

    console.log(LowTemperature);
    console.log(HighTemperature);

    temps_data_low.push(LowTemperature);
    temps_data_high.push(HighTemperature);

    // Update the page:    
    for (var i = 0, count = temps_data_low.length; i < count; i++) {

        if (temps_data_low.length > 1){
            day = day - 1;
        }

        sum_low += temps_data_low[i];
        sum_high += temps_data_high[i];

        temp_data_msg += month + "/" + day + "/" + year + ' ' + temps_data_low[i] + " " + temps_data_high[i] + "<br>";

    }

    calc(LowTemperature,HighTemperature,temp_data_msg,temps_data_low,temps_data_high,sum_low,sum_high);
}

function calc(LowTemperature,HighTemperature,temp_data_msg,temps_data_low,temps_data_high,sum_low,sum_high) {

    'use strict';   

    if (temps_data_low.length === 1) {

        temp_data_msg += "Averages " + LowTemperature + " " + HighTemperature + "<br>";
    }

    else {

        temp_data_msg += "Averages " + (sum_low/temps_data_low.length) + " " + (sum_high/temps_data_high.length) + "<br>";
    }   

    // Display the messsage

    output.innerHTML = temp_data_msg;

    return false;

}

// Initial setup:
function init() {
    'use strict';    
    document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = call;
} // End of init() function.
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Can you put your code in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never reset your `temp_data_msg` variable.

So each time there is a form submission you are appending all the same data to the previous output.

You can fix it by adding `temp_data_msg = '';` just before your `for` loop in the `call` function:

```
function call() {

//omitted...

temps_data_low.push(LowTemperature);
temps_data_high.push(HighTemperature);

temp_data_msg = ''; //<----- this line

// Update the page:    
for (var i = 0, count = temps_data_low.length; i < count; i++) {
    //omitted...
```

This will have the side effect of trashing your headings, so at the top of the script where you declared `temp_data_msg` I changed it to

```
var temp_data_header = "Date" + ' ' + "Low Temperature" + ' ' + "High Temperature" + '<br>';
```

Then when you output the final text:

```
output.innerHTML = temp_data_header + temp_data_msg;
```

Comment: I made the changes, but when I submit the form now, it just flashes the text and goes away.

Comment: add an `e` or `event` parameter to your `call()` function. i.e., `call(e)`. The first line in `call()` should now be `e.preventDefault()`. At the moment when you hit submit it is submitting the form and navigating you away from the page. Since the form action is probably blank it defaults to the same page. So effectively reloads it.

Comment: i added call(e) to the init function and added e.preventDefault() under the function call() {}. Is that it? still not working

Comment: I see what happened, it works now. I hadd call(e) under init and it was undefined. I removed it, works now. Thanks